# How to move nodes to a desired position?

Tags: javascript, graph-visualization, arbor.js

I want to move a specific node (say i have the node reference), to a desired location (say to the top left corner of the canvas). I tried doing something similar to one in the sample project, where they move nodes while dragging with the mouse. But it doesn't seem to work. I am not seeing the node move as i expected. This is the code i have.

```
$("#someElement").click(function() {
  sys.eachNode(function(node, pt) {
    if (node.name === "specificNode") {
      // moveToOrigin
      var s = arbor.Point(1, 1);
      var p = sys.fromScreen(s);
      node.fixed = true;
      node.p = p;
      node.fixed = false;
      node.tempMass = 1000;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe call some Refresh() like method? Have you already managed to accomplish this? I'm also trying...

Answer (score 1):

To move a node to a desired position get the desired position relative to the canvas and set it via particle system's `fromScreen(...)` function:

```
var point = point;
var pos = canvas.offset();
var s = arbor.Point(point.x-pos.left, point.x-pos.top);
node.p = particleSystem.fromScreen(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set position of node first, then again iterate each loop for nodes.

```js
redraw: function () {
    gfx.clear()

    particleSystem.eachNode(function (node, pt) {
        //var node = particleSystem.getNode("Carrol Wahi")
        if (node.data.color == "yellow") {
            var pos = $(canvas).offset();
            var point = particleSystem.fromScreen(arbor.Point(pos.left + 150, pos.top));
            node._fixed = true;
            node._p = point;
            //console.log("x=" + point.x + ", y=" + point.y);
            node.tempMass = .1
        }
    });

    particleSystem.eachEdge(function (edge, pt1, pt2) {
        //   your code goes here
      }
    particleSystem.eachNode(function (node, pt) {
       //your code goes here
    })
```

}